# PhpStorm keeps asking for configuring "Incoming Connection From Xdebug" while I already have a server config

Tags: docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I have installed Xdebug on my PHP container. For completion sake: I start php-fpm, nginx, mysql and redis using docker-compose.

The config used in xdebug.ini:

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so

xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=host.docker.internal
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_connect_back=0
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_children=-1
xdebug.var_display_max_data=-1
xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
xdebug.remote_log="/tmp/xdebug.log"
```

I use port 9001 to no collide with php-fpm.

[image]

I keep getting this dialog, and even when clicking OK, it does not break on my breakpoints:

[image]

The servers config:

[image]

Comment: Maybe your Xdebug IDE config is for local installations, and not the one hooked up in a container.

Comment: Are your mappings correct? Try enabling xdebug logs per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/troubleshooting-php-debugging.html#collect-xdebug-logs  and check what does it say.

Comment: As per your Incoming Debug Connection screenshot, the server name that comes from request is empty. Please configure your web server (nginx as I understand) so it uses the server name. if it has it, make sure that php-fpm gets that info as well. P.S. AFAIK, once configured, the server name must match the one from "Host" field on "PHP | Servers" screenshot

Comment: @Ástþór Yes I double checked and I mapped the code to the server pretty simply to `/code` using a docker-compose volume

Comment: @LazyOne For some reason another container works out of the box (a wordpress container)

Comment: @onlineThomas That's my best suggestion thus far. Try it, as it's definitely helping (at very least did in the past; although they may have implemented some fix for that). If still nothing -- collect Xdebug log from both ends: PHP (`xdebug.remote_log`) and IDE and check what it may say about it: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241115-How-to-Collecting-PhpStorm-WebStorm-debug-Logs **P.S.** Definitely share those logs, ideally showing real paths.

Comment: @onlineThomas Another idea, especially if you have created that "PHP | Servers" entry yourself manually.  Delete it and try to debug (activate phone handle icon first) -- this will bring that "choose mapping" dialog and will create new config from scratch. Once done -- compare to yours/see if it will behave any better.